# MongoDB geointersect fail to find big polygons

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I'm using mongo to store some geolocalized data, with the goal of retriving them using $geointersect. Specifically I have this document stored in my db:

```
  {
    "loc": {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -179.875,
              -89.875
            ],
            [
              179.875,
              -89.875
            ],
            [
              179.875,
              89.875
            ],
            [
              -179.875,
              89.875
            ],
            [
              -179.875,
              -89.875
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
          "name": "urn:x-mongodb:crs:strictwinding:EPSG:4326"
        }
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {}
    },
    "_id": "576af8e31d41c87fa1f1d04f"
  }
```

Which as you may notice covers almost the entire World. Now it doesn't matter what coordinates I input for my $geointersect query, it will never be returned... Does anyone know why?

An example of the query I'm using could be:

```
[
  {
    "loc.geometry": {
      "$geoIntersects": {
        "$geometry": {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "coordinates": [
            [
              [
                13.4307861328125,
                41.599013054830216
              ],
              [
                13.9801025390625,
                41.599013054830216
              ],
              [
                13.9801025390625,
                41.80407814427234
              ],
              [
                13.4307861328125,
                41.80407814427234
              ],
              [
                13.4307861328125,
                41.599013054830216
              ]
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "loc": 1
  }
]
```

Of course the coordinates of the query are contained inside the polygon in the saved document (I mean... it's as big as the the world, duh!) but for some reason it doesn't find any match... I'm kinda lost.

Comment: Same problem man, did you find the solution?

Comment: unfortunately, i didn't. But it appears that if you select in your query an area big enough, it will show.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking into this now. If the polygon is solid and bigger than an earth's hemisphere, mongo returns everything outside of the area. check out their big poly and crs in the geoWithin documentation

Comment: i knew about that, problem is... you can use their crs only on the input polygon, not on the ones that are saved in the db. if i have a polygon larger than en emisphere in my database.... well it's hard to fetch it.